# Why is the `return_value` for CliRunner().invoke(...) object null?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, pytest, python-click

I'm using click v8.1.3 and I'm trying to create some pytests, but I'm not getting my expected `return_value` when using `click.testing.CliRunner().invoke`

```py
import click.testing
import mycli

def test_return_ctx():
  @mycli.cli.command()
  def foo():
    return "Potato"
  
  runner = click.testing.CliRunner()
  result = runner.invoke(mycli.cli, ["foo"])

  assert result.return_value == "Potato" # this fails. b/c the actual value is None
```

I tried updating the root command to return some random value as well to see if we get a value there

```py
# mycli
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
  return "Potato"
```

But it didn't help. `return_value` for the `Result` object is still `None`

Am I misunderstanding how I should return a value from a command?

https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.testing.Result.return_value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click command handlers do not [return a value](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/api/#click.testing.Result.return_value) unless you use: [`standalone_mode=False`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/exceptions/#what-if-i-don-t-want-that).  You can do that during testing like:

```py
result = CliRunner().invoke(foo, standalone_mode=False)
```

#### Test code:

```py
import click
from click.testing import CliRunner


def test_return_value():
    @click.command()
    def foo():
        return "bar"

    result = CliRunner().invoke(foo, standalone_mode=False)

    assert result.return_value == "bar"
```

#### Test Results:

```
============================= test session starts ============================
collecting ... collected 1 item

test_code.py::test_return_value PASSED                                   [100%]

============================== 1 passed in 0.03s ==============================
```

Comment: It's so cool that there are people who this kind of _secret_ stuff! ;D I read both links and I have no idea how you figured out that by setting `standalone_mode` to `False` will make `return_value` work since the documentation only mentions that `system.exit()` won't be called, but not that other stuff will start to work.

Comment: @t3chb0t, I learned this, as well many of "the secrets" of the other answers I built for click, by spending a considerable amount of time reading the click code.